# PHP json_encode an array & store return in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to store a php array as `JSON` in mysql. for that I have `meeting_point_json` column with type='longtext'.

here is the array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 23/4/2012
            [meeting_time] => 23:04
            [meeting_place] => town hall
            [venue] => London
            [opponents] => Tigers
            [official_incharge] => Mr Putin
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 23/4/2050
            [meeting_time] => 13:04
            [meeting_place] => chief office
            [venue] => Kenya
            [opponents] => Peococks
            [official_incharge] => Mr Black
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => dsad
            [meeting_time] => sadas
            [meeting_place] => jjjjj
            [venue] => jjjj
            [opponents] => dasds
            [official_incharge] => asad
        )

)
```

and here is the php code:

```
$data = json_encode($_POST['team_meeting_pt']);
    $sql = "UPDATE yami_sub_team set meeting_point_json = $data where id = $subteam_id";
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
        exit("Done!");
    }else{
        die('Something went wrong, changes not saved. Error details: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

it should work but Instead, I get an error:

```
Something went wrong, changes not saved. Error details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"1":{"date":"23\/4\/2012","meeting_time":"23:04","meeting_place":"town hall","ve' at line 1
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the full value of $data?

Comment: what If _POST [''team_meeting_pt] is empty or worse NOT SET ?

Comment: @Svetlio Or worse, an attempt to hack his database? :)

Comment: @BerryLangerak atleast json_encode will mess up the attack .. :)

Comment: @Svetlio Yeah, but still... there's a security hole now. In fact, the reason he gets this error is because he is injecting non-SQL into his SQL statement ;)

Comment: Are you *sure* that you want to store a *serialisation* of your structured data in an RDBMS?

Comment: @ShaunBohannon - Its the array that I have pasted above.

Comment: @BerryLangerak & Svetelio - I know but This is not the final code, i am just testing storing data as json into mysql. further, this is wordpress so need to check if it supports `mysqli` or `PDO`. Does wordpress support it?

Comment: @eggyal - Yes, its flexible as I am expecting data-schema to change quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See at:
`$data` variable change with `".$data."`
and
`$subteam_id` variable with `".$subteam_id."`

remember the sql query only sent as strings, not variable inside there...
and do it to your all way to write PHP. Always wrap variable with ".." and '..'

".." and '..' are depending by your strip wrapper:
For example:
If look like this
`$string = mysql_query("SELECT DATA FROM ".$variable."");`
So, you must use ".." wrapper !
and if like this
`$string = mysql_query('SELECT DATA FROM '.$variable.'');`
So, you must use '..' wrapper !

Good luck friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this line instead of your:

```
$sql = "UPDATE yami_sub_team SET `meeting_point_json`='".$data."' WHERE `id`='".$subteam_id."';";
```

Comment: Still prone to SQL injection. Use `mysql_real_escape_string`, or rather, don't use the deprecated mysql_* functions and choose PDO with a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE yami_sub_team set meeting_point_json = '" . mysql_escape_string($data) . "'where id = $subteam_id";
```

You can read more about that function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "'" . mysql_escape_string(json_encode($_POST['team_meeting_pt'])) . "'";
```

Change at 1st line

Answer (score 0):

first  I would use a prepare statement. and bind results to it to avoid all the hard ships.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//replaced $data with ? for security reasons
$sql = "UPDATE yami_sub_team set meeting_point_json = ? where id = $subteam_id";
$stmt->$conn_prepare($sql);
//binds data to the ?
// the 's' states string is replacing  ?
$stmt->bind_param('s',$data);
if($stmt->execute()){
{
     exit("Done!");
}else{
    die('Something went wrong....);
}
```